# Does sip provider can control sip video quality?

Tags: sip, pjsip, videocall

I am working on a sip video call using pjsip on android. I have tried all possible way to improve video quality .but still i get same bad video quality. Does sip provider controls video quality as well ?

Answer (score 0):

It can have impact as it is involved with codec negotiation being in the middle of signaling path, but it is also quite likely that even if operator does something video media parameters are ignored anyway.

You can try direct IP calls to remove provider from the equation.